# Part-of-Speech Tagging with Lucene

Tags: lucene, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I'm building an emotion recognition system for chat applications. In that the core part is finding the verb  in the user entered text, which can be done with a part-of-speech tagger.
Is it possible to build a part-of-speech tagger with Lucene? If not, what is a good open-source/libre software package or system I can use?

Comment: Finding verbs is called part-of-speech (POS) tagging, not semantic role labeling (SRL). SRL is about detecting the types of the arguments of the semantic predicate (which needs not be a verb). It's not clear to me what exactly you expect the POS tagger or SRL system to do to make it useful for emotion recognition. Finally, what do you mean "build such a system *with* Lucene"? Use Lucene to build it? Feed the results into Lucene?

Comment: Edited in response to your comment, @jogojapan.

Answer (score 0):

From Lucene you would probably want to use Mahout. I've used Mahout's Bayes classifier for sentiment analysis from Lucene, which worked fairly well and was relatively easy to set up. I think the major benefit of Mahout+Lucene vs. anything else would be that it scales better.

There are tons of open source frameworks to do this with if you don't like Mahout. I've found NLTK to be very user friendly, for example, although I don't think it integrates with Lucene very well.